# Is there a way to have a form with a fixed value that is still visible?

Tags: html, css, forms

Is there a way to have a form that holds a pre set value (numbers or letters) that cant be changed by the user and isnt hidden to them. I need to so when someone clicks on a product the product id and price is auto filled out, they only need to type in the quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set the value on the HTML form `<input>` using the `value` attribute as always and disable the input by using the `disabled` html attribute.

Something like this:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
   First name: 
   <input type="text" name="fname" value="John" disabled ><br>
   Last name:
   <input type="text" name="lname" value="Doe"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

the value will be there and the field will be disabled.

Hope it helps,